# Expression Trees .net

Tags: .net, functional-programming, expression, expression-trees

I would like to get a good grasp on the subject, hence want to ask following questions to the community:

1. What benefits do expression trees bring to table?
2. What exactly does this statement mean: "Expression Trees are data compiled as code"?
3. What common challenges do the Expression Trees and functional programming in the context of .net solve?
4. What are good online resources to get up the speed on the subj?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. They bring the ability to take your source code and "understand" it at execution time - LINQ providers being the prime target of this
2. Well, expression trees are often built from source code (e.g. converted lambda expressions) but instead of that source code being compiled into an *executable* form it's built into a tree which other code can inspect. (More precisely, the compiler takes source code, and emits executable code which in turn builds an expression tree at execution time.)
3. Expression trees and functional programming seem somewhat orthogonal to me, to be honest. Both often deal with higher order functions, but that's about it.
4. [MSDN perhaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)?

Comment: Does Linq use expression trees for all implementations? Linq-to-SQL? Linq2Objects? Linq2Xml? Does it also mean that if you are to build your own Linq provider (implement IQuaryable<T> and IQueryProvider) will require implementation of expression trees and if yes why and how (high level of course)?

Comment: @Max: No, only some implementations use expression trees. For LINQ to Objects, for example, the lambda expressions are just compiled to delegates. (LINQ to XML isn't really a LINQ provider - it's an XML API which just plays well with LINQ to Objects.)

Comment: If you build your own LINQ provider implementing `IQueryable`, you'll be presented with expression trees representing the queries - you then need to examine those expression trees and convert them to the appropriate format.

Answer (score 6):

> What benefits do expression trees bring to table?

Expression trees allow a program to manipulate a portion of it's own implementation at runtime in a simplified manner. They allow expressions to be passed around as a representation of their structure, rather than as just a delegate that can be invoked.

> What exactly does this statement mean: "Expression Trees are data compiled as code"?

Languages prior to C#/.NET have supported this kind of manipulation ... the best example being LISP. The ability to represent the structure of a program in a data structure within the program is referred to as [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity). C# supports a limited for of homoiconicity in the form of expression trees. The C# language allows the creation of expression trees transparently from (a subset) expressions in your code. For example:

```
int x = 3;
Expression<Func<bool>> IsXLessThan4Expr = () => x < 4;

Func<bool> IsXLessThan4 = () => x < 4;
```

The variable `IsXLessThan4Expr` is a captured from the lambda expression as an expression tree. We can now traverse the representation of that expression, if we like to understand what it's structure is - and manipulate it, if we desire. The delegate `IsXLessThan4`, by contrast, cannot be inspected ... it can only be invoked. You could, of course, always get the raw IL for any method (assuming you have the necessary permissions) - but it's far more difficult to reverse the logical structure of a program from IL than from an expression tree.

> What common challenges do the Expression Trees and functional programming in the context of .net solve?

The best example of the use of expression trees to solve a non-trivial problem is in LINQ-to-SQL, where the implementation of `IQueryable` is able to transform query expression trees written in C# into equvalent SQL queries that can be executed by a database.

Expression trees also make it possible to generate C# code on the fly - since expression trees can be compiled into lambdas. Here's an example of that:

```
var paramNotification = 
      Expression.Parameter(typeof (NotificationEntry), "noti");

Func<NotificationEntry, bool> predicate = 
        m_PredicateExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<NotificationEntry, bool>>(
            Expression.LessThan(
                Expression.Property(paramNotification, "Value"),
                Expression.Constant(100)),
            new[] {paramNotification})
        .Compile();
```

The above snippet creates an expression that compares the `Value` field of a `NotificationEntry` object to some supplied constant (100) - and compiles that into a lambda we can call.

> What are good online resources to get up the speed on the subject?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) is probably your best bet at the moment.

Comment: Ok, so can one call an expression tree a dynamic peice of code that represents a logical expression to manipulate some data that can be applied to a structure at runtime?

Comment: @Max: Not exactly. The expression tree is not itself code. It's a data structure. You can *transform* an expression tree into code using `Compile()` - which will return an appropriate delegate.

Comment: I think your answer helped me understand the subj a lot. Thank you! What I did not know before is that the main diff between a delegate or lambda and expression is that expression can be analyzed and manipulated before the code decides to invoke it. Hence the implementation of the visitors class in many Linq2Whatever Provider implementations, correct?

Comment: @Max: Yes, exactly. There are many `IQueryable` implementations that use the ability to inspect and transform expression trees to allow C# code to represent queries against other kinds of resources. They do this by visiting the representation of the expression and transforming it into a form appropriate to their domain. What's really nice is that in C# a lambda can be transparently passed to any method that accepts a parameter of type `Expression<...>` - this allows consuming code to be written in a natural manner without worrying about the underlying details of the transformation.

Comment: great, this makes perfect sense, so I guess I am ought to write my own Linq Provider in order to understand the mechanics better.